# Programmatically Create Video from PowerPoint Slide Show (MacOS)

Tags: vba, macos, video, export, powerpoint

Does anybody know how to get this to work on PowerPoint for MacOS?

```
Sub TestCreateSampleVideo()
    ' Change the file path and name as required.
    CreateSampleVideo ActivePresentation, "C:\TEMP\Video.wmv"
End Sub

Sub CreateSampleVideo(pres As Presentation, fileName As String)
    ' Presentation.CreateVideo does its work asynchronously.
    ' You can use the Presentation.CreateVideoStatus property
    ' to periodically check the status, and react accordingly.

    pres.CreateVideo fileName, DefaultSlideDuration:=1, VertResolution:=480

    ' Now wait for the conversion to be complete:
    Do
        ' Don't tie up the user interface; add DoEvents
        ' to give the mouse and keyboard time to keep up.
        DoEvents
        Select Case pres.CreateVideoStatus
            Case PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusDone
                MsgBox "Conversion complete!"
                Exit Do
            Case PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusFailed
                MsgBox "Conversion failed!"
                Exit Do
            Case PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusInProgress
                Debug.Print "Conversion in progress"
            Case PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusNone
                ' You'll get this value when you ask for the status 
                ' and no conversion is happening or has completed.
            Case PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusQueued
                Debug.Print "Conversion queued"
        End Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg985312(v=office.14).aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? Did you get an error message? What did the error message say?

Comment: a) Have you tried passing the CreateSampleVideo subroutine a filename that's acceptable on MacOSX?  and b) Have you checked the object browser in the VBA IDE to learn whether the methods and constants used in the sample are even defined?  In PowerPoint 2011 the various ppMediaTask constants are available but the CreateVideo method is not. Perhaps it's been added in PPT 2016/Mac.

Comment: Still doesn't work on MacOS. But got it to work perfectly on Windows. That's ok for now. Thanks for help! ;)